# Image loader issue: Too many DML statements: 1 Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, dmlexception

I'm trying to create interface for loading images and here is my code:

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="LogoManager" contentType="text/html" readonly="true">
    <head>
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">            
            function FileSize() {
                var fileInput = $('#idFileUpload');
                var maxSize = fileInput.data('max-size');
                if(fileInput.get(0).files.length)
                {
                    var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
                    if(fileSize>maxSize)
                    {
                        alert('file size is more than 2MB');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {                       
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Please select the file to upload');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <apex:form id="upload-form">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <br/>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!accountID != ''}">
                <h2>Account Name: <label>{!accountName}</label></h2>
                <br/><br/>
                Please select image: 

<apex:inputFile value="{!doc.body}" filename="{!doc.name}" id="file"/>
                <br/><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Upload" onClick="if (FileSize() === false) { return false; }" action="{!SaveAttachment}"/>   
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!accountID == ''}">
                No valid account selected
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Controller code:

```
public with sharing class LogoManager{    
    public String accountID { get; set; }
    public String accountName { get; set; }
    public String attBody { get; set; }
    public LogoManager()
    {
        accountID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID');
        if (accountID == null)
        {
            accountID = '';
        }
        if (accountID != '')
        {
            Account a = [select Name from Account where id = :accountID];
            if (a == null)
            {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please upload a jpg file'));

            }
            else
            {
                accountName = a.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    public Pagereference SaveAttachment()
    {
        doc.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        doc.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId(); //update this folder to Account Logo Folder        
        try
        {
            insert doc;
        }
        catch (DMLException e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            doc.body = null; // clears the viewstate
            doc = new Document();
        }       
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'File uploaded successfully'));
        return null;
    }

    public Document doc
    {
        get 
        {
            if (doc == null)
            {
                doc = new Document();
                doc.Name = accountName;
                doc.description = '';
                doc.keywords = '';
            }
            return doc;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

I get following error:

> Too many DML statements: 1 Error is in expression '{!SaveAttachment}'
>   in component  in page logomanager:
>   Class.LogoManager.SaveAttachment: line 46, column 1

Not sure what is causing this error and how do I go about fixing it. Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Too many DML statements: 1 Error

means your `apex:page` readonly attribute false

[**Setting Read-Only Mode for an Entire Page**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm)

> Giving the attribute readonly will give that element the readonly
>   status. It doesn't matter what value you put after it or if you put
>   any value after it, it will still see it as readonly. Putting
>   `readonly="false"` won't work.

Issue related to your VF page is `readonly="true"` means you can't perfom DML in controller

Just change this to `readonly="false"`

or you can remove this attribute. `readonly` attribute default value is `false`